# how would a client connect to a server set to INADDR_ANY?

Tags: c, sockets, server, tcp, serversocket

I am super confused on how a client would connect to a server with its struct sockaddr_in set to ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

after a bind call, the servers listening socket would be set to INADDR_ANY, how would a client even connect to a socket set to INADDR_ANY?

What is the address that the client would pass into the sockaddr_in struct before the connect() system call? Is it the ip address of the server, I am so confused.

Here is the code for a basic super unreliable server I am playing around with...

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> /*socket()*/
#include <netinet/in.h> /*struct sockaddr_in*/
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[32];
    int ssockfd, csocadsz, nwsockfd;
    unsigned short int ptnum;
    struct sockaddr_in ssockaddr, csockaddr;
    unsigned long int addr;
    ssockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    
    ssockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    
    printf("Enter port number: ");
    scanf("%hu", &ptnum);
    
    ssockaddr.sin_port = htons(ptnum);
    ssockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    
    bind(ssockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &ssockaddr, sizeof(ssockaddr));
    
    listen(ssockfd, 5);
    
    csocadsz = sizeof(csockaddr);
    
    nwsockfd = accept(ssockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &csockaddr, &csocadsz);
    
    read(nwsockfd, string, 31);

    printf("Here is the message: %s\n", string);

    write(nwsockfd, "I got your message lol\n", 24);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want to write a client that connects to this server, but I am stumped as to what I pass into its name.sin_addr.s_addr parameter.

EDIT: HERE IS THE INCOMPLETE CLIENT PROGRAM.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int clisockfd;
    unsigned short int port_number;
    char sipad[12], string[32];
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    
    printf("Enter port number: ");
    scanf("%hu", &port_number);
        
    printf("Enter servers &ip: ");
    scanf("%s", sipad);
    
    clisockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(port_number);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = /*What do I input here?*/
    
    connect(clisockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    
    printf("Please enter a message without whitespace: ");

    scanf("%s", string);
    
    write(clisockfd, string, strlen(string));
    bzero(string, 256);
    
    read(clisockfd, string, 31);
        
    printf("%s\n", string);
    
    return 0;
}
```

What do I put where the comment says "/*What do I input here?*/"?

Comment: Binding to `INADDR_ANY` and then listening on the port is really saying, "Accept connections that come to any IP address on this host".  Whereas if you bind to `127.0.0.1`, for example, you'll only get inbound connections to `localhost` and not `192.168.1.7`.  When bound to `INADDR_ANY`, you'd `accept()` inbound connections to both.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Please explain to me like I am incompetent: What do you mean by;" Accept connections that come to any IP address on this host". Does a computer have like, multiple &ips. (I am being completely serious)

Comment: (My previous comment was misguided — consider it what happens after waking up from a Sunday afternoon nap.)  A single host machine may have multiple network cards and therefore have multiple IP addresses.  With INADDR_ANY, a client can connect to any of the addresses and the server program will get the connection request.

Comment: @BING_BOTTY Yes, computers can have multiple IP address.  If you're on a Windows system, bring up a `cmd` window and enter `ipconfig /all`.  On a Linux system, it would be `ifconfig -a`.  You'll likely see multiple IP address, both IPv4 (`127.0.0.1`) and IPv6 (`fe80::6710:df20:b2df:ac5f`).  If you bind to `INADDR_ANY`, you'd be able to accept connections to any of those IP addresses.  If you bind only to `127.0.0.1`, you'd only get connections to that IP address (not quite true, but close enough for now - `localhost` is a bit different than "normal" network IPs.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I read the wikipedia for Host, and it said "internet hosts and other IP hosts have one or more IP addresses assigned to their network interfaces." Is a network interface a socket, thus meaning a socket has a specific ip address? If thats the case, what function do I use to get the ip address from that socket, so that a client can input that into the struct sockaddr_in?

Comment: @BING_BOTTY A "network interface" is usually something like a WiFi connection or the somewhat-larger-than-a-standardp-phone-landline plug (RJ-45) that gets a network cable plugged into it.  Those are physical interfaces.  Multiple IP addresses can be assigned to any physical interface in a lot of different ways.

Comment: @BING_BOTTY A socket is an already established connection between two machines, with two addresses/ports (one on each end). Andrew's comment above describes what a network interface is. If the client and server are on the same local network, you can run `ifconfig` (Linux) ([example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt0sN.png)) or `ipconfig` (Windows) on the server to get the address associated with the relevant interface (ethernet or wifi) and then try using that address on the client. If the client and server are on the same computer, you can use `127.0.0.1` for localhost....

Comment: ... if on different machines on the same home/corporate network, you'll need to know the IP address of the other machine. If on separate networks, things get more complicated unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind a socket you specify the IP address the kernel should accept connects on. That allows you to bind only so connections coming in on specific networks that have access to the specified address. For example if you bind the socket to 127.0.0.1 then only clients running on the same system and using IPv4 can connect and nothing from the outside.

If you specify INADDR_ANY for bind then you bind to all the addresses the system has or will have in the future. It's a wildcard allowing connections from anywhere.

Think of the IP address you specify in bind as a filter. Only if the IP address the client connects to matches that specified in bind then the connection will happen. INADDR_ANY matches every address there.

Answer (score 0):

`INADDR_ANY` refers to the every machine's ip, meaning that you can bind, connect, etc at all IPs at the same time.

I would recommend find the main internet IP if you want to connect from another device or localhost IP which is `127.0.0.1` to connect from same device.

### Finding IP address

```
char hostname[128];
gethostname(hostname,128);
hostent *host=gethostbyname(hostname);
in_addr ip=*((in_addr *)host->h_addr_list[0]);
```

variable `ip` is your ip

We create an array of characters called `hostname`, then we pass it into the function called gethostname, its argument 1 is the array in which to store hostname and argument 2 is size of that array

After, we create a pointer of type hostent and store the value returned by `gethostbyname` in it.

Then take the value from pointer `h->h_addr_list` and type-cast it to `in_addr`

Comment: *First of all, `sin_addr` has a anonymous union called `S_un` or `s_un` having `s_addr` or `S_addr`*  [No - `s_addr` **must** be accessible as a top-level member of the `in_addr` structure](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html):  "The `<netinet/in.h>` header shall define the `in_addr` structure, which shall include at least the following member: `in_addr_t  s_addr`", and `in_addr_t` is just a 32-bit unsigned integer: "`in_addr_t`  Equivalent to the type `uint32_t` as described in `<inttypes.h>`."  Any other detail is implementation-specific.